# How to set default browser in Windows 7 via script?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

I'm working on a system imaging process during which both Chrome and Firefox are installed silently.  I'm trying to find a way to set Firefox as the default browser for both the system default user (so any new user that logs in has FF set as default) and the current user.

The Firefox docs say that this should accomplish that, but it doesn't work:

firefox.exe -silent -setDefaultBrowser

Using process monitor I can see that the command above is doing a bunch of stuff to the registry, but after I run it my default browser hasn't been set to Firefox.

If I open Firefox and go to Tools > Options > Advanced  and click the  Set FF as Default Browser" button, that does work.

The problem is I don't want to have to perform manual steps every time a new laptop gets deployed so I need to find some way to accomplish the same thing from the command line.

I tried using process monitor to see what values Firefox was setting when that button is clicked so I could manually duplicate them a different way but when I click the set default button in FF procmon quite literally I see over 250 registry writes by firefox.exe and I don't really want to track them all down.

Can anyone help me figure out why firefox.exe -silent -setDefaultBrowser doesn't work or offer another way to set FF as the system/user's default browser?

Comment: For a change in the default browser of all users, a script won't do the job and the browser installers can't do it for you. The default browser gets configured in the sub-keys of the `\Software\Classes` keys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. (And there's a *lot* - you have to account for each file type and action the browser is meant to handle.) You could configure a global setting in HKLM, but most responsible browser installers will only set it in HKCU. Even if you change it in HKLM, conflicting settings in HKCU will override it. To fix that, what you need is a Group Policy.

Comment: If this is a `Software/Classes` change, why can't an account-level process change it? Is it a certainty that it must be under `HKLM`? For reference, I *am* able to write an account-level process that registers its own `mymadeupurihandler://mywebsite.com` handler.

Answer (score 5):

The registration is done by the `helper.exe`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe /SetAsDefaultAppGlobal`

For the sake of completeness, if someone wants to change the default browser only for the current user

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\uninstall\helper.exe /SetAsDefaultAppUser`

Comment: This does indeed set the default browser for the current user, so thanks for that!  After running these commands, if I login to a new profile on the PC and open a web link, it does open in Firefox but Firefox still tells the user it's not the default browser and asks them if they want to set it as such.  Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Do you launch the new profile with the same Firefox executable?

Comment: I didn't no.  I thought the first command you provided was supposed to do set FF as the default for the default system user (i.e. every new profile that is created).

Comment: Then I guess by new profile you mean new windows user account. Yes, I verified that accounts created after Firefox is set as the default browser, ignore that setting. I think you should ask if there is a group policy that allows to execute a script, once, the very first time a user logs on.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is, but there is definitely an option for executing scripts every time a user logs on.  It's easy enough to have the script create a blank text file somewhere under the user's' profile folder so the script can tell if it's already run and if so, not run again.  I guess I'll go that route.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but you may be able to set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command` in order to accomplish this.